# SQL ETL for creating a table - job interview question

Tags: sql, sql-server

i had a sql test for a job i wanted but unfortunately i didn't get the job,

i was hoping someone can help me with the right answer for a question in the test,

so here is the question:

ETL Part
Our “Events” table (Data source) is created in real time. The table has no updates only appends.

```
event_id    event_type  time                user_id    OS           Country
1           A           01/12/2018  15:39   1111       iOS          ES
2           B           01/12/2018  10:43   2222       iOS          Ge
3           C           02/12/2018  16:05   3333       Android      IN
4           A           02/12/2018  16:39   3333       Android      IN
```

Presented below Fact_Events table that is part of our DWH. This table aggregates the number of events on hourly level. The ETL process is running every 30 min.

```
date        hour    event_type_A    event_type_B    event_type_C
01/12/2018  15:00   1               0               0
01/12/2018  10:00   0               1               0
02/12/2018  16:00   1               0               1
```

Please answer the following questions:

1. Define the steps to create the Fact_Events table
2. For each step provide the output Table.
3. Write the query for each step.
4. What loading method you would use?

I really appreciate any help as i wish to learn for future job interviews.

thanks in advance,

Ido.

/*******************here is my answer****************/

please tell me if i am correct or if there is a better solution,

ETL Part

1.
Create a table for each event, in this case we will need 3 tables,
Use UNION ALL to concatenate all the table to one table.

2.
First step:

```
date        hour    event_type_A    event_type_B    event_type_C
01/12/2018  15:00   1               0               0
02/12/2018  16:00   1               0               0
```

Second step:

```
date        hour    event_type_A    event_type_B    event_type_C
01/12/2018  15:00   1               0               0
02/12/2018  16:00   1               0               0
01/12/2018  10:00   0               1               0
```

Third step:

```
date        hour    event_type_A    event_type_B    event_type_C
01/12/2018  15:00   1               0               0
02/12/2018  16:00   1               0               0
01/12/2018  10:00   0               1               0
02/12/2018  16:00   0               0               1
```

3. 

```
SELECT Date(time) as date,
              Hour(time) as hour,
Count(event_type) as event_type_A,
0 as event_type_B,
0 as event_type_C
FROM Events
WHERE event_type = 'A'

Union All
SELECT Date(time) as date,
              Hour(time) as hour,
0 as event_type_A,
Count(event_type) as event_type_B,
0 as event_type_C
FROM Events
WHERE event_type = 'B'

Union All
SELECT Date(time) as date,
              Hour(time) as hour,
0 as event_type_A,
0 as event_type_B,
Count(event_type) as event_type_C
FROM Events
WHERE event_type = 'C'
```

4. 

I would use incremental load,
At the first time we will run the script over all the data and save the table,
From now on we will concatenate only the new events that aren’t exists in the saved table.

Comment: "Define the steps to create the Fact_Events table" - the first question alone has **many** very different solutions. We can't answer these questions for you because there's no single right answer.

Comment: i updated the post, so you can see my answer and let me know if i am in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loading query is way off.  You need to group and pivot.

Should be something like this:

```
select Date(time) as date,
       datepart(hour,time) as hour,
       Sum(case when event_type='A' then 1 else 0 end) as event_type_A,
       Sum(case when event_type='B' then 1 else 0 end) as event_type_B,
       Sum(case when event_type='C' then 1 else 0 end) as event_type_C
from Events
group by Date(time), datepart(hour,time)
```

Comment: thank you David, i forgot to group, i see that now, and the query you wrote is a lot easier to maintain, i would love to hear you're thought about section 4, What loading method you would use?

Comment: This is a good and simple approach. I've just come to thinking, though, it may not be that easy. We may detect a new event type in the new data. That would mean we'd have to add a column to the destination table and consider the additional type in the query.

Comment: For loading method always bulk load and retain the raw data.  Then build the facts and dimensions from that.

Answer (score 0):

In my shop, I'm not heavily involved in hiring, but I do take a large part in determining if anyone is any good - and hence, you could say I play a big part in firing :(

I don't want people stuffing up my data - or giving inaccurate data to clients - so understanding the overall data flow (start to finish) and the final output are key.

As such, you'd need a much bigger answer to question 1, potentially including questions back.

- We group data hourly, but load data every half hour. The answer has to work for these.
- What do we want if there are no transactions in a given hour? No line, or a line with all 0's? My gut feel is the latter (as it's useful to know that no transactions occurred but is not guaranteed.

Then we'd like to see options, and an evaluation of them e.g.,

- The first run each hour creates new data for the hour, and the second updates the data, or
- Create the rows as a separate process, then the half-hour process simply updates those.

However, note that the options depend heavily on answers to the previous questions e.g.,

- If all-zero rows are allowed, then you can create the rows then update them
- But if all-zero rows are not allowed, then you need to do insert on the first round, then updates and inserts in the second round (as the row may not have been created in the first round).

After you have the strategy and have evaluated it, then yes - write the SQL. First make it accurate/correct and understandable/maintainable. Then do efficiency.

Comment: Note that nobody gets all the questions when just thinking about it - you always run into new questions while writing it. But thinking about the problem and process first (rather than the code) hopefully spots the big questions before you spend hours coding.